# SlimDX Wrong Joystick State on startup

Tags: joystick, slimdx, gamepad

I use SlimDX and DirectInput to handle a XBox 360 Gamepad for Windows. Everything is working fine but I have the following problem:

When a button is pressed while starting the application, the button state is NOT shown as pressed in the joystick state. The same with the analog sticks: if I hold the stick fully in one direction on startup, the position is shown as zero and changes upon first little movement of the stick.

Is there a way to get the real state of the joystick at startup ?

Answer (score 0):

Using XInput instead of DirectInput solves the problem.